# How to change Swap partition to add more

Tags: laptop, swap, minecraft

I play a lot of Minecraft/Tekkit. I have quite a bit of lag issues and my brother told me to add more VM RAM. He said it's called Swap Partitioning on Linux. I am looking for a simple solution, I can't access my su(it's not accepting my password). I am running Ubuntu 13.04. I have 2gb RAM and 250 hard drive space. Please help. My laptop is a Presario Compact from the stone age, does that change anything?

Comment: "I can't access my su(it's not accepting my password)" You are never going to get this to work without your sudo password.

Answer (score 1):

- in Ubuntu, you use `sudo` to temporarily gain root privileges. you generally don't use `su`, although you can do `sudo su` or `sudo -i`
- you need root privileges to change the partition layout on your disks, and swap is usually handled as a partition in Ubuntu.
- i recommend to use `gparted` to change your partitions. install it via software centre if it is not installed.
- add another swap partition in `gparted` on unused disk space. if you do not have any unused disk space left, you have two options:

  - resize existing partitions (MAKE A BACKUP FIRST, and possibly you need to do the resize from a live-cd boot)
  - consider using a swap file instead of a swap partition: see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

generally a good read: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: I loaded gparted and it says I have 49.49MiB available on /boot. Is that space usable to create a swap?

Comment: 50 MB is not enough. we are talking about gigabytes that are (probably) needed here. also, leave the partition for /boot alone as it contains low level stuff and configuration, including your bootloader and kernels. tell us more about the other partitions or use the swap-file approach mentioned above, as it is less error-prone/causes less serious problems if something goes wrong.

Comment: Well I read both web pages above before I posted here. One of the two sites says that I should see the swap partition on gparted. I do not see a swap partition there, but If I go to System Monitor it shows that I have 83.5 MiB(4.1%) of 2GiB. So I'm not sure what the problem is.